# How to get the folder size in Digital Ocean Spaces

Tags: api, object, storage, digital-ocean

I want to know that is there any way to get the size of a folder inside Digital Ocean "Spaces"?

In my PHP application I want to allocate space to different users. Each user will have their folder in "Spaces". So I want to get the folder size of user's folder so that my application can prevent him to upload more if it exceeds the quota limit.

Answer (score 0):

Since Digital Ocean Spaces is AWS S3-Compatible solution, and AWS S3 does not have this option because folders are just a simplified way of grouping files (it's prefixed in the file path inside a bucket).

One possible solution is to get the size of the file when uploading it and save this information together with your user. This way you can calculate if the user is exceeding his quota limit.